# fseeko, ftello等のLinuxのライブラリ・コール・コマンドをCygwinで利用する事は出来ますか？

Tags: linux, cygwin

現在、Windows上にCygwinをインストールして、計算環境を構築しようとしているのですが、Linuxのライブラリ・コール・コマンドの [fseeko,ftello](https://kazmax.zpp.jp/cmd/f/fseeko.3.html) が利用できなくて悩んでおります。これらのライブラリを導入する事は可能なのかどうか、ご存知の方居ましたらお教え頂け無いでしょうか？

Comment: 承認は付いていないですが、このオプション指定あたりが対処方法になりそうです。[Alternatives to fseeko for Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20573123/9014308)

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。ご紹介頂いたリンクは自分も見つけたのですが、目的がfseeko,ftelloを用いているソフトのインストールの為、ソースコードをいじるとどこかに影響が出そうで躊躇しておりました。ただ、オプション指定をしてみるというのは試していなかったので、そちらは検討させて頂こうと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

オイラのところの [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) x64 では何もしなくても `ftello()` が使えました。
[cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) x64 64bit 版に更新してみるとよいかも

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 DESKTOP-*** 3.0.7(0.338/5/3) 2019-04-30 18:08 x86_64 Cygwin
$ cat ftest.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { return ftello(stdin); }
$ gcc ftest.c
$
```

`ftell` / `fseek` と `ftello` / `fseeko` の違いは 2GiB 以上の大きなファイルが扱えるか否か。 [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) x86 の場合 `long` が 32bit であるため `fseek` では 64bit offset が扱えない (ので `off_t` を使う `fseeko` を使わざるを得ない) に対し、そもそも [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) x64 の場合 `long` は 64bit なので `fseek` と `fseeko` は同じものです。

[cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) x86 版にていろいろ試したいのであれば `/usr/include/sys/features.h` を読んで `gcc` のコマンドラインオプションの追加を試してみるとよし。

`_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` が `#define` されていると `fseeko` や `ftello` が使えるよ、という記述があるので

```
$ gcc -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE ftest.c
```

で先のソースもリンクできるはず（未テスト）

Comment: 調べてみたところ、まったく同じバージョンで、ftest.cを試してみたところ同じ結果が得られました。エラー原因はどうやらテンプレートで親クラスのメンバへのアクセスで出てくるエラーの様なので、更にそちらの対処方法を調べてみたいと思います。